# How to evaluate to a condition every single value in a list (Matlab)

Tags: arrays, matlab, loops, for-loop, vector

First the problem asks to  the user to write down 20 numbers; then all that values should be evaluated with the conditions "<0", "==0" and ">0" and to add that value into another variable such as "negative numbers", "zeros", "positive numbers" and finally the program should display the list of numbers;
I tried like this:

```
negatives=[];
positives=[];
zero=[];
inputone=input("first number:");
if inputone==0
zero=[zero,inputone];
elseif inputone>0
positives=[positives,inputone];
elseif inputone<0
negatives=[negatives,inputone];   
end
```

and so I did 20 times, and it works but what I need is to make it easier, or shorter; and what I am wondering is how to evaluate that 20 numbers, maybe to make a list of all the 20 numbers and to make a for loop to evaluate every value of the list, but I have not found any information.

Comment: You state that the code works, but it only asks for a single number and it does not print it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure whether you want the list of numbers (as inputted) in this case you have to modify this code example. I have written some code for you, since it seems you are not familiar with basic constructs as for loops: you mentioned you repeated the same code many times; should I have misunderstood, please disregard this post.

So, far from being the best solution, at least this code shows some basic practices and constructs I highly encourage to look at:

you want to encapsulate your logic in elementary functions, 
define main parameters outside, 
pre-allocate memory (vector) for performance, 
using logical indeces to filter matrix components, 
use for loop for executing repetitive functions over enumeration of data (I personally prefer more functional constructs, like cellfun, but Matlab is limited in its functional style and I think it would add just confusion, at this point).

```
numberOfInputs = 20;

[ negativeVec , zeroVec, positiveVec ] = categorizeInputs(numberOfInputs);


function [negVec, zerVec, posVec ] = categorizeInputs(numberOfInputs)

% pre-allocation: not crucial in this case, but a good habit
negPosMat = zeros(numberOfInputs,2 ) ;

% this is just a counter for the number of zeroes: we do not need to store
% the zeroes since there is only one element; it suffices to store the
% number of occurrences
nzeroes = 0;

% for the number of inputs requested
for iNewInput = 1 : numberOfInputs
    % ask for next input and store into actual number
    actualNumber = input("Insert next number: ");

    % udate matrix of positive and negatives and number of zeros
    % occurrences
    [negPosMat , nzeroes] = updateMatrixOfCategories(actualNumber, negPosMat , nzeroes , iNewInput) ;
end

% create the zero vec (as per user request, but number of occurrences would
% suffice)
zerVec =  zeros(nzeroes ,1) ;

% negative numbers are store on first column: extract only the nonzero
% entries
negVec = negPosMat( negPosMat(:,1) ~= 0 , 1 ) ;

% positive numbers are store on second column: extract only the nonzero
% entries
posVec = negPosMat(negPosMat(:,2) ~=0, 2);

end

function [actualMat, nzeroes] = updateMatrixOfCategories(number, actualMat , nzeroes, rowNumber)
if (number == 0)
    nzeroes = nzeroes + 1; 
elseif number > 0
    actualMat(rowNumber , 2 ) = number;
elseif number < 0
    actualMat(rowNumber , 1) = number; 
end
end
```